# Change div height on click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an info bar at the bottom of my page that has a "Notes" link. At the moment when clicked it will display a div. You can see this [here](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com). Now, I need "Notes" do also change the height of "date", which is the id of the bar's height to around 98% so you can see the entire div. (It can't be pixels because the webpage is fluid.)

My current javascript is this:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("permalinkpage");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
var cat = document.getElementById("date");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "show";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "hide";
}
} 
</script>
```

Where ele is the div displayed on click, text is the "Notes" link, and cat is the black bar at the bottom that needs to be extended to 98% of the screen/page.

Now, here is the HTML:

```
<div class="date">

<div class="tags">
{block:HasTags}{block:Tags}<span class="tag"><a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a></span>   
{/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}
</div>

<div class="info">
{block:NoteCount}<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">{NoteCount}</a> <img   
id="heart" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/gWmlq420u/heart.png"> 
{/block:NoteCount}
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
{block:Date}{MonthNumber} {DayOfMonth} {ShortYear} <img id="clock"   
src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/9Gels3y49/clock.png">{/block:Date}</div> 

{block:IndexPage}
<div id="permalinkpage"><object id="permalinkbaby" type="text/html" data="{Permalink}">
</object></div>
{/block:IndexPage}

</div>
```

Thankyou so much in advance! :-)

Edit:

None of those worked.

Comment: Don't use `<script language="javascript">`. Use a HTML5 doctype instead and omit any additional attributes.
`<script>`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use $("#divID").css("height","value");

Comment: So $("#date").css("height","100%");  ?

Answer (score 1):

with jquery

```
$("#idDiv").attr("height","value");
```

in  javascript

```
var divId=document.getElementById("id");
    divId.setAttribute('height','value');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$("#divID").height(value);
```

Comment: For value can I just put "100%"

Comment: use this to fill full document 
var ht = $(document).height();
$("#divID").css('height',ht)
OR
var ht = $(document).height();
$("#divID").height(ht);

Comment: Neither worked... I placed ht where all the variables are and I posted $("#divID")etc.. in the last sequence.